# Is it possible to alias a hostname in Linux?

Tags: linux, hostname, alias

Is it possible to alias a hostname in Linux?

It has been asked by jmillikin at various Ubuntu forums as follows:

---

*[Is it possible to create a hostname alias? Sort of like /etc/hosts,
but with other hostnames rather than IP addresses. So that with some
file like this, you could ping "fakehost1", and it would be re-mapped
to "realhost", and then "realhost" would be resolved to an IP address.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=455800)*

```
# Real host        # Aliases
realhost           fakehost1 fakehost2 fakehost3
```

---

Somebody has answered about ssh, but not about ping, etc. My main
purpose is to use it as an alias for a [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) server. In my case, realhost
is under a dynamic IP address. So, the "/etc/hosts" alias doesn't work. I want to
access my Subversion server as `svn://my_svnserver/my_repos` instead of
`svn://realhost/my_repos`.

Comment: I guess I may be missing something. Are you saying you couldn't have /etc/hosts look like 10.0.3.4 some.host.org another.domain.com You have to use a reference for some programmatic reason?

Answer (score 80):

For those who don't have an account on the forums (or don't wish to login):

> if your main issue is not to ping but to ssh, you can create/edit your
>   ~/.ssh/config adding lines like these:

```
Host fakehost1
  Hostname real-hostname

Host fakehost2
  Hostname real-hostname2

Host fakehost3
  Hostname real-hostname3
```

Comment: The Hostname part needs to be on a new line. Here is a good tutorial on how to make a config file like this: http://mattryall.net/blog/2008/06/ssh-favourite-hosts

Comment: good workaround, thanks. But of course, better solution would be to use cnames on dns

Answer (score 41):

Linux supports aliasing by setting the HOSTALIASES env variable.

```
echo "fakehost realhost" > /etc/host.aliases
echo "export HOSTALIASES=/etc/host.aliases" >> /etc/profile
. /etc/profile
```

then you can

```
ping fakehost
```

N.B. ping requires you to set this up as root, but you can do it as any user for any application that runs as that user. ping suids to root.

Comment: didn't work for me on Ubuntu 12.04 :(

Comment: The HOSTALIASES only work for executables that are don't have the setuid flag set. So it won't work for ping (unless you're already root when executing ping). I guess this is done to avoid tricking setuid-executables into connecting to a different host than it intented.

Comment: Also does not work for curl

Comment: Works great for maven with poms from Windows users :-)

Comment: does not work on centos 6.4 either.

Comment: it will rarely end up in the expected result.

**HOSTALIASES only works for applications using getaddrinfo(3) or gethostbyname(3)** - This mean that it will work for applications trying to explictly resolve the hostname by a specific system call: It is never the case.

see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts

so the only solution is local dns (dnsmasq)

Comment: Seems this is trick is deprecated.
 The gethostbyname*(), gethostbyaddr*(), herror(), and hstrerror() functions are obsolete.  If your system runs DNSMasq locally you can alias in that for any resolution that uses DNS.

Comment: Does not work. When pinging, got the following: `ping: fakehost: No address associated with hostname`

Comment: Ashark, try ping as root (with the env var), or try anything that does not use setuid to see if this works for your desired application.

Comment: teknopaul, yes pinging from root user works.

Comment: Works for me on CentOS 8...

Comment: does not work on my debian 11.3

Answer (score 26):

You can setup this on your DNS server, CNAME records allow a machine to be known by more than one hostname. So add CNAME records to your DNS server like that :

```
fakehost1 IN CNAME realhost 
fakehost2 IN CNAME realhost 
fakehost3 IN CNAME realhost
```

Comment: a light-weight DNS server to try would be `dnsmasq` (it also serves DHCP).

Answer (score 22):

I often do this with environment variables. I know this only works for the command line, but it is where I am most often craving hostname aliases (I worked with several supercomputer accounts, all with long URLs).
Here's an example, if you're using BASH.
In ~/.bashrc:

**export fakehost="long.ass.annoying.url.org"**

then, in a fresh shell:

**ssh christopher@$fakehost**

Answer (score 11):

The only way this can be done is if you have your own local dns server.

Comment: Yeah, now it seems the only solution. Thanks. Cannot upvote since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: If the ever-changing IP address of a DSL or dialup connection is the issue, dyndns is a better solution, IMHO.

Comment: No, it's not a better solution. Once the server has a hostname that is handled by something else then all the OP needs is a CNAME for the first hostname. DYNDNS and similar rely on the host informing the dns server that it's ip has changed.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need an dyndns server that will map your current IP address to a hostname. You'll tell this server about your current IP address whenever you login, and it will update your hostname record.

Answer (score 5):

The use of /etc/hosts.aliases is a standard feature of the bind resolver libraries.  It's more robust than adding entries to /etc/hosts and can be used if you can not add CNAMES to your DNS (don't have access to it).

In general the best practice is to use CNAMES in the DNS with appropriate SEARCH defined in /etc/resolv.conf.

Updating /etc/hosts is not very robust as entries have to be kept in sync with IP changes.  This only really works on a small scale or when you are using a name service to distribute the hosts map (eg via ldap).

Another solution may be DNSMasq http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq

Comment: I tried using /etc/hosts.aliases in CENTOS 6 but this feature does not seem to work.  Nor can I find any documentation on its use or existance.  Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do

in .basrhc

```
[distro defaults]
source ~/.bashrc_custom # only relevant to this host
source ~/.bashrc_common # useful to have on any machine
                # sync this to any host I manage.
```

in ~/.bashrc_custom

```
[host relevant config]
source ~/.bash_lib/net.host
```

in ~/.bash_lib/net.host

```
#-*- shell-script -*-

#             /\             /\
#            |`\\_,--="=--,_//`|
#            \ ."  :'. .':  ". /
#           ==)  _ :  '  : _  (==
#             |>/O\   _   /O\<|
#             | \-"~` _ `~"-/ |
#            >|`===. \_/ .===`|<
#      .-"-.   \==='  |  '===/   .-"-.
# .---{'. '`}---\,  .-'-.  ,/---{.'. '}---.
#  )  `"---"`     `~-===-~`     `"---"`  (
# (            Infra système             )
#  )                                     (
# '---------------------------------------'
alias net.host.ad.principal.rdp='krdc rdp://a.chaouche@192.168.100.21'
alias net.host.dns.rdp='krdc rdp://administrateur@10.10.10.4'
alias net.host.dns.ssh='ssh root@10.10.10.7 -p <port>'
[...]

#             /\             /\
#            |`\\_,--="=--,_//`|
#            \ ."  :'. .':  ". /
#           ==)  _ :  '  : _  (==
#             |>/O\   _   /O\<|
#             | \-"~` _ `~"-/ |
#            >|`===. \_/ .===`|<
#      .-"-.   \==='  |  '===/   .-"-.
# .---{'. '`}---\,  .-'-.  ,/---{.'. '}---.
#  )  `"---"`     `~-===-~`     `"---"`  (
# (               Infra web              )
#  )                                     (
# '---------------------------------------'

alias net.host.appsrv.ssh='ssh root@10.10.10.83 -p 22022'
alias net.host.cloud.ssh='ssh root@cloud.algerian-radio.dz'

#             /\             /\
#            |`\\_,--="=--,_//`|
#            \ ."  :'. .':  ". /
#           ==)  _ :  '  : _  (==
#             |>/O\   _   /O\<|
#             | \-"~` _ `~"-/ |
#            >|`===. \_/ .===`|<
#      .-"-.   \==='  |  '===/   .-"-.
# .---{'. '`}---\,  .-'-.  ,/---{.'. '}---.
#  )  `"---"`     `~-===-~`     `"---"`  (
# (            Infra messagerie          )
#  )                                     (
# '---------------------------------------'
alias net.host.messagerie.backup.ssh='ssh -lroot 192.168.100.25 -p 44044'
alias net.host.messagerie.prep.ssh='ssh root@192.168.100.19 -p 44044'
alias net.host.messagerie.secours.ssh='ssh root@10.10.10.20 -p 44044'
[...]




[... plus other sections ...]
```

On the command line, I can do

```
$ net.host.bandit.ssh
```

this will connect to bandit.labs.overthewire.org
changing the destination of this is as easy as editing my .bash_lib/net.host file

I can also do :

```
$ net.host.ksc.rdp
```

to rdp to 192.168.100.12 as user a.chaouche

etc.

You can think of any command you like.
The general template is

```
alias net.host.<host>.<command>='<command> <host address specification>'
```

Another approach would be to store the host address specifications as global env variables as suggested by christopher.
I do this for files and directories I like to cd to.
For example :

```
~ $ cd $MAIL_<tab>
$MAIL_LASTPASS         $MAIL_NEWUSERS         $MAIL_ROUNDCUBEFOLDER  $MAIL_SCRIPTS
~ $ cd $MAIL_SCRIPTS
/usr/local/scripts/mail $ ls.count
219
/usr/local/scripts/mail $ type ls.count
ls.count is a function
ls.count ()
{
    set -- $1*;
    echo $$
}
/usr/local/scripts/mail $
```

So you can have the same type of variables to use for hosts

```
ssh  $HOST_MAIL
nmap $HOST_WEBSERVER
ping $HOST_SVNSERVER
```